# Static Inner Classes Bytecode Java

Tags: java

I have a test class:

```
public class Test {

    private static class Nested1 {
        Nested2 n2 = new Nested2();
    }

    private static class Nested2 {
        Nested1 n1 = new Nested1();
    }

}
```

As I understand, `static` nested classes are regular `static` member of the enclosing class, that are still top-level classes. When I compile the above code, I get four files:

1. `Test$1.class`
2. `Test$Nested1.class`
3. `Test$Nested2.class`
4. `Test.class`

Compiled from "Test.java"

```
class Test$Nested1 {
  Test$Nested2 n2;
  private Test$Nested1();
  Test$Nested1(Test$1);
}
```

My questions:

1. Why do I have an additional class `Test$1.class`.

   ```
   class Test$1 {
   }
   ```
2. Why does `Test$Nested1.class'` constructor have an input of type: `Test$1`?

Test.java

```
public class Test {  

    private static class Nested1 {
        Nested2 n2 = new Nested2();
    }

    private static class Nested2 {
        Nested1 n1 = new Nested1();
    }

}
```

I am using Java 1.8.

Comment: the de-compiled code is not a valid java class. perhaps it is meant to be `Test$Nested1(Test$1){}`

Comment: This is the class I get from javap -p. Why do you say it's invalid?

Comment: did you try to compile? the methods have no bodies. the class either has to be declared `abstract` or add method bodies

Comment: @SharonBenAsher what are you talking about? there are no methods, why does he need to have methods in his classes? he pasted **compiled** `.class` file

Comment: @SharonBenAsher javap never shows the method body, just tried.

Comment: Not reproducable. I do not get `Test$1.class`!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I do. At least with Java 8.

Comment: Using javac, I get the four files.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Java 1.8.0_172.

Comment: Ah! With Java 8 I also get this class. Important information that must be included in the question!

Comment: Just curious, is it a real case or accidental findings?

Comment: Was just brushing up on my inner classes knowledge. Created a fast example, stumbled upon this.

Comment: the additional `Test$1.class` is probably a synthetic class. see proposed duplicate for details

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I think that's the answer, thanks man.